# Trailing slash at end of URL bug .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My problem is, when I enter `http://example.com/admin/` it works well, `$_GET['decode']` contains right information and I can work with it. But when I enter `http://example.com/admin` (without slash), my URL redirects to `http://example.com/admin/?decode=admin` and everything is messed up. Could someone helps me?

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks

<FilesMatch "(config.php|defines.php|functions.php)">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ ./index.php?decode=$1 [L,QSA]

php_value date.timezone "Europe/Bratislava"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `mod_dir` is adding a trailing slash in the directory URI (`/admin`) after your last rule is run by `mod_rewrite`.

Try this code:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks

<FilesMatch "(config.php|defines.php|functions.php)">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ./index.php?decode=$1 [L,QSA]

php_value date.timezone "Europe/Bratislava"
```

Comment: try now. I added `DirectorySlash Off` at top.

Comment: test in a new browser.

Comment: I forgotten to say, I have folder named `admin`, but why firefox takes it right?

Comment: +1, this is awesome. @debute, clear your chrome cache. 301 redirects are cached, so Chrome is not even requesting the file in the browser from your server.

Comment: @zx81 thanks, I didn't know before, that redirects are cached, good point.

Comment: Thanks @zx81, yes 301 is cached by browsers. Always better to use 302 in testing and change it to 301 after verifying rules.